# How to make every object in a list a float

Tags: python, multiplication

I'm using Python 2. When I try to multiply objects in a list it just repeats the same thing twice even though i have tried to use this to resolve the issue:

```
map(float, prices)
```

The code i'm using is:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

prices = []
htmlfile = urllib.urlopen("http://www.fifacoin.com/default/quick/listwithcategoryid?        category_id=6").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlfile)
for item in soup.find_all('tr', {'data-price': True}):
    prices.append(item['data-price'])

map(float, prices)
print prices[1] * 2
```

This code just outputs the value of prices 2. I'm new to Python so it's probably something obvious

Comment: What is your problem and what is your expected result?

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is, but you aren't assigning the result of `map(float, prices)` anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`map` does not change the original list; it simply returns a new list. Try:

```
prices = map(float, prices)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try a list comprehension:

```
answer = [float(i) for i in prices]
```

Output:

```
In [253]: prices
Out[253]: ['5', '1', '3', '8']

In [254]: [float(i) for i in prices]
Out[254]: [5.0, 1.0, 3.0, 8.0]

In [255]: prices
Out[255]: ['5', '1', '3', '8']
```

Note that the original list remains unchanged